# The label from \subfigimg macro hided in xepersian

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, xepersian

When use the "\subfigimg" macro with xepersian environment, the labes over each image missing:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Zar}
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-1\baselineskip}{\textbf{\color{red}#2}}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{}}
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{الف}{example-image-a} &
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{ب}{example-image-b} &
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{پ}{example-image-c} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are underneath.

Because of symmetry, there should be maybe six combinations (done in the correct sequence) leading to the desired result, of right and left overlap, and image and text.

This version puts the labels first, then overlaps them onto the images, with same margins on both sides, and the labels are on the left-hand side of the image:

[image: text on top]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}%[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}%Zar}
\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
\leavevmode%{\usebox1}% Print image
{\phantom{\usebox1}}% Insert appropriate spcing
\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-1\baselineskip}{\textbf{\color{red}#2}}}% Print label
\llap{\usebox1}
%    \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{}}
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{الف}{example-image-a} &
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{ب}{example-image-b} &
        \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{پ}{example-image-c} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edited to add**

The key is, with `xepersian`, that `{A}\llap{B}` means `A` is put on top of `B`. `\rlap` does the normal text-flow direction.

I need something similar, with option of the text in either top left (TL), top right (TR), bottom left (BL), or bottom right (BR) corner of the image, using `if` statements. Plus, with text on images, I added `bidicontour`, which makes the text easier to read.

Here is top right position:

[image: text on images RTL]

Close-up:

[image: close-up]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[outline]{bidicontour}%before xepersian


\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Niloofar}

\newcommand\imagea{}
\newcommand\texta{}

\newif\ifcaptionBR
\newif\ifcaptionTR
\newif\ifcaptionBL
\newif\ifcaptionTL

\newcommand\capinit{%
\captionBRfalse
\captionTRfalse
\captionBLfalse
\captionTLfalse
}
\newcommand\capimage[2]{%1=image,2=text,(3=location: global)
\ifcaptionBR%
{#2}\kern-\wd2{#1}
\fi%
\ifcaptionTR%
{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-\baselineskip}{#2}}\kern-\wd2{#1}
\fi%
\ifcaptionBL%
{\phantom{#1}}\llap{#2}\llap{#1}
\fi%
\ifcaptionTL%
{\phantom{#1}}\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-\baselineskip}{#2}}\llap{#1}
\fi%
}

\newcommand\subimg[4]{% 1=width,2=image,3=text, 4=text location command
\renewcommand\imagea{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}
\renewcommand\texta{{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\bidicontour{yellow}{#3}}}}}
\setbox1=\hbox{\imagea}
\setbox2=\hbox{\texta}
\capinit
#4
\capimage{\imagea}{\texta}
}

\bidicontourlength{0.8pt}

\begin{document}

%
%\subimg{0.30\linewidth}{example-image-a}{الف}{\captionTLtrue}
%
%
%\subimg{0.30\linewidth}{example-image-a}{الف}{\captionBLtrue}
%
%
%\subimg{0.30\linewidth}{example-image-a}{الف}{\captionTRtrue}
%
%
%
%
%\subimg{0.30\linewidth}{example-image-a}{الف}{\captionBRtrue}


\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{\hspace{1mm}}p{0.33\linewidth}@{}}
        \subimg{0.98\linewidth}{example-image-a}{الف}{\captionTRtrue} &
        \subimg{0.98\linewidth}{example-image-b}{ب}{\captionTRtrue} &
        \subimg{0.98\linewidth}{example-image-c}{پ}{\captionTRtrue} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

It is an exercise in symmetry groups and the 'handedness' of (2-axis) reflections. Very interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your response